# How to give Circle layer clustering property to json files created in mapbox studio

Tags: android, mapbox

I created custom styles by using Mapbox studio with multiple points.

I implemented this style in my android app within a `mapview`. 
Since there are so many point locations I need to cluster these points into circles with a count.

Can anyone help me to cluster these JSON styles based on its count?

My style [URL](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/thamjeed/cjupa53c14d171gqsana7xbt7.html?fresh=true&title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidGhhbWplZWQiLCJhIjoiY2p1Z3Z4MzBxMHF4bzQzcWpsbjlneDZqayJ9.fHoVDY8iXBXesHM8Zbg5cQ#5.3/13.600000/78.700000/0)

I have seen circle layer clustering for GeoJson files as in the [URL](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/clustering/#circlelayer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, clustering option is not available in the Mapbox Studio, you'll have to add required sources and layers manually, in the runtime. Checkout [these examples](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/clustering/).